# Allow the user to resize views on an iPad App?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have an iPad application with a uitableview on and a uitextview below it. I would like to allow the user to drag the boarder between the views to adjust their size the way most panels on desktop applications can be resized. Is there an easy way to do this on iOS? If not what would be the best way to customize the views to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to subclass your `UITextView` and register for `Touches`, with that you know where the user's finger is, and you can adjust your frame based on that.
The `UIResponder` class reference will give you more help.

[UIResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)